# How to select mysqli for tags search using php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to select mysqli for tags search using php ?

I have table : test like this

```
 ___________________________________________
|_id_|_______name_______|________tag________|
| 1  |        dog       |  animal,pet,dog   |
| 2  |       donuts     |    food,donuts    |
| 3  |       BMW        |         car       |
| 4  |     football     |       sport       |
| 5  |     ferrari      |    car,supercar   |
```

and this is mysqli php code for select

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE tag = '$_GET[tag]' order by id desc";
```

Then i test my code by this url

```
www.example.com/search_tag.php?tag=car
```

But it will show only row id `3` , how to select for show row id `3` and `5` ?

Comment: Better normalize your data. For the time being you can use `FIND_IN_SET` like `... WHERE FIND_IN_SET(your_input_tag,tag) > 0 ...`. Must read for you [**Is storing delimited list really that bad?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: like this `$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE FIND_IN_SET($_GET['tag'],tag) > 0 order by id desc";` ?

Comment: dont even bother with that, fix the db structure

Comment: could you please give me some sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

As @nogad suggested on the comment section, fix your database structure. I would suggest to separate a table for storing the tags for each name.

First, let's create a table for storing different tags (`tags_tb`):

```
tags_id | tags_desc
--------+----------
   1    |   animal
   2    |    pet
   3    |    dog
   4    |   food
   5    |   donuts
   6    |    car
/*** LIST GOES ON ***/
```

Then, create another table for storing the subjects (`subject_tb`):

```
subj_id | subj_desc
--------+----------
   1    |    dog
   2    |   donuts
   3    |    BMW
/*** LIST GOES ON ***/
```

Then, create a table for storing the related tags for each subject (`selected_tags_tb`):

```
 id | subj_id | tags_id
----+---------+---------
  1 |    1    |    1
  2 |    1    |    2
  3 |    1    |    3
  4 |    2    |    4
  5 |    2    |    5
  6 |    3    |    6
```

So, when a user selects a tag (for example, the user selects the tag - `animal`, all subjects that relates to that tag will be shown), a simple query will do it:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM selected_tags_tb a
    LEFT JOIN subject_tb b ON a.subj_id = b.subj_id
    WHERE a.tags_id = ?
```

This approach will make your system dynamic.